# Why is my NSNumber always nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So for some reason, in a certain method, my `NSNumber` is always `nil` and its driving me nuts.

If the user selects a row in my picker, this gets called and it works fine:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    self.query.activityLevel = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[self.activityArray objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"key"]intValue]];
}
```

However, when the user doesn't pick a row, and just continues to the next VC, I have a check to see if `activityLevel` is `nil` and to set it to `1` if so.

```
- (void)donePressed {
    if (!self.query.activityLevel) {
        self.query.activityLevel = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
    }
    NSNumber *calories = [Calculations numberOfCaloriesNeededForQuery:self.query];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The problem is, whenever the user doesn't pick a row and it hits `self.query.activityLevel = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];`, if I print the object, it is still `nil`.  I have no idea why.  I set a breakpoint and it is hitting that line...

Comment: two questions:  1) are you using ARC and 2) is query not nil?

Comment: I am using ARC and yes, it seems like query is nil.  However if the user selects a row, it is not nil.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you get nil because the value of `self.query` is also nil, so you are setting a value on nil object and you get nil ...

It is a little bit confusing but while in another language you usually get a NullPointer exception in these kind of situations, in objective C it is legal to send a **message** to nil  so keep attention at these situations ...

Comment: I know that is a little bit confusing, because in another language usually you will get a NullPointerException, but in objective C it is legal to send a message to nil, so keep attention on these kind of cases ...